# How is SharePoint linked to other Office 365 programs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, team-sites, office-365-groups

I know that a SharePoint team site is equivalent to an Office 365. When a SharePoint team site is created, an Office 365 group is created.

How far is SharePoint linked to other Office 365 programs, or in other words, what features/integrations does SharePoint offer me with regard to the Office 365 group?

I have seen that I can integrate an Office 365 group calendar on modern sites, what other advantages are there?

Answer (score 0):

By default, each SharePoint team site is part of an Office 365 group. An Office 365 group is a single permissions group that is associated with various Office 365 services. This includes:

1. SharePoint site
2. An instance of Planner
3. A mailbox
4. A shared calendar
5. OneDrive
6. Microsoft Teams Channel
7. A shared OneNote notebook
8. Yammer Conversations for group, etc.

> **Important**: Currently, integration with Office 365 Groups is only available with SharePoint Online and only if Office 365 Groups has been enabled by your administrator. If you're an administrator, see [Manage who can create Office 365 Groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/4c46c8cb-17d0-44b5-9776-005fced8e618) for the steps to enable Office 365 Groups for your organization. Without Office 365 Groups integration, you will not have access to Office 365 Group resources such as a shared Outlook inbox or shared Outlook calendar.

**Source**: [Integration with Office 365 Groups in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-sharepoint-team-site-75545757-36c3-46a7-beed-0aaa74f0401e).

**References**:

1. [Team site permissions and Office 365 Groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions#team-site-permissions-and-office-365-groups).
2. [Office 365 Groups or SharePoint Team Sites?](https://sharepointmaven.com/office-365-groups-or-sharepoint-team-sites/)

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

You and your team can collaborate and communicate easier through Office 365 group you can use

1. Shared Outlook Inbox (Email / Conversations)
2. Shared Yammer Group (Chat)
3. Shared Outlook Calendar (Calendar)
4. Shared SharePoint Document Library (Document Repository)
5. Shared OneNote Notebook (Common Notebook)
6. Shared SharePoint Team Site (Project / Team Site)
7. Shared Planner (Task Management)

[Use_Office_365_Group_for_team_collaboration](https://www.steeves.net/news/5-reasons-use-office-365-groups-team-collaboration/)

[Office365_Group](https://sharepointmaven.com/office-365-groups-or-sharepoint-team-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 Groups is a service that works with the Office 365 tools you use already so you can collaborate with your teammates when writing documents, creating spreadsheets, working on project plans, scheduling meetings, or sending email.

Shared Inbox– For email conversations between your members. This inbox has an email address and can be set to accept messages from people outside the group and even outside your organization, much like a traditional distribution list.

Shared Calendar – For scheduling events related to the group.

SharePoint Document Library– A central place for the group to store and share files.

Shared OneNote Notebook – For gathering ideas, research, and information.

SharePoint Team Site– A central repository for information, links and content relating to your group.

Planner– For assigning and managing project tasks among your group members.

Reference: [Learn about Office 365 Groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2#ID0EAACAAA=Use)